# Get mailbox creation date with Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: email, microsoft-graph-api, office365, exchange-server

Is it possible to get mailbox creation date with Microsoft Graph API?

The most convenient approach that I've found is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getmailboxusagedetail?view=graph-rest-1.0. But that is not very helpful, since all data is anonymized by default on server side.

Comment: What exactly is anonymized in that report? I would use the same report. You need userPrincipalName and createdDate.

Answer (score 0):

That property isn't exposed via the Graph outside of the Reporting endpoint but it sounds like you have anonymization turned on in the tenant so it won't be usable. I would suggest using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-exomailbox?view=exchange-ps. This is a REST call under the covers but Microsoft don't support you using the API directly.